# User Made Matlab Function Fails Once All Variables are Cleared

Tags: matlab, function, differential-equations

I originally asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50902603/using-subs-function-to-evaluate-output-of-dsolve-give-extra-output-in-maltab) yesterday and found the answer myself; however, I used the `clear all` command in Matlab and now the function throws an error `Undefined function or variable 'y'`.
I used the code from my answer 
function [s1] = L_Analytic3(eqn,t0,h,numstep,y0)

```
%Differential Equation solver for specific inputs
%   eqn is the differential equation
%   t0 is start of evaluation interval
%   h is stepize
%   numstep is the number of steps
%   y0 is the initial condition

syms y(x)
cond = y(0) == y0;
A = dsolve(eqn, cond);
s1 = A;
S1 = s1;
for x = t0 : h : h*(numstep)
    subs(x);
    if x == t0    
        S1 = subs(s1,x);
    else 
      S1 = [subs(S1), subs(s1,vpa(x))];
    end
end
end
```

and also put `L_Analytic3(diff(y) == y,0,0.1,5,1)` into the Command Window after entering `clear all`. I have to run a seperate code

```
syms y(x)
cond = y(0) == 1;
A = dsolve(diff(y) == y, cond);
```

before using my function in order for the function to work. Is this just because `A`,`ans`,`cond`,`x`, and `y`, are already defined by the 3 line code before using the function? If so, is there a way that I can use the function without having to use that 3 line code first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `L_Analytic3(diff(y) == ...);` you do not have variable y defined, so MATLAB complains - it has no way of knowing `y` is a symbol that will be defined in the function you are calling. You do not require all 3 lines of code. `syms y(x)` should be enough to define y and lets you use the function call you wanted.

Now, there are 2 easy ways to fix this that I see:

1. A script (or another function) that has `syms y(x)`, followed by the call to `L_Analytic3` the way you are doing it (which now does not need `syms y(x)`, it has been defined already).
2. Give anonymous equation as the input instead, say `@(x) diff(x)==x`, and change a line of `L_Analytic3` slightly to `A = dsolve(eqn(y), cond);`

Both ways work fine for this, no idea if 2nd one breaks in more complex cases. I would likely pick 1st version if you are doing symbolic stuff, and 2nd if you would like to have same function call to both numeric and symbolic functions.

Comment: I put it into a script and defined the variable inputs and it worked perfectly. Thanks @Zizy Archer